# Firebase Functions Custom Domain with Single Page App

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, single-page-application, firebase-hosting

I have a Firebase hosted single page app.

I also have 3 Firebase functions (contact, plans, features) that the app and external sources make requests of.

My app has a custom domain, which I'd like to access my functions via.

This is my current `firebase.json` config

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So currently all traffic goes to my app and routing is handled via my SPA. Access to my functions currently has to be done via the `cloudfunctions.net` URL which isn't ideal.

How can I add URL rewrite entries to this config so that my functions are accessible via my custom domain *and* my single page app handles the rest of the routes?

I have tried the following for the `features` endpoint:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/features/**",
    "function": "features"
  },
  {
    "source": "!/features/**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Where in my functions `index.js` I have:

```js
...
exports.plans = functions.https.onRequest(plansApi);
exports.features = functions.https.onRequest(featuresApi);
exports.contact = functions.https.onRequest(contactApi);
```

But I receive `404 Cannot GET /features/123` as the response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things:

1. Make sure that your `featuresApi` handler is matching for the **full URL path** (e.g. `/features/123` not `/123`). Firebase Hosting forwards the full path to the function, not just the `**` part.
2. Rewrites are resolved in order, so there's no need to do `!/features/**` for your second rewrite source. `**` should be fine since if it matches `/features/**` it will already match the first rewrite and resolve to the function.

Based on the error message, it seems likely that (1) is the culprit here.

Comment: Brilliant, it was #1, is this documented and I just missed it?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have the same issue and custom domain started working once I've added full URL path in each function, as you described in p-1. Is there any way to workaround, or do you have any suggestions to keep old URLs at *.cloudfunctions.net working for backwards compatibility ? I've added a gist with my sample code https://gist.github.com/rilian/dbc3ed86cf6b1365e1bdd4c2db469048

Comment: Like if you have an Express app... Your POST-request is maybe: `/api/user/:task` and your Express app is defined in the variable `appAPIUser` and exported like so: `exports.appAPIUser = functions.https.onRequest(appAPIUser);` you should have a rewrite rule for hosting named like this (to include the correct parameters):  `{
        "source": "/api/user/**",
        "function": "appAPIUser"
      }`.

Comment: And on server side if you are using *cookie-session* (NPM) you can do something like: `req.sessionOptions.domain = req.hostname === 'us-central1-{{project-name}}.cloudfunctions.net' ? '{{project-name}}.web.app' : req.hostname;` and `req.sessionOptions.secure = req.secure`. Works good for me.