# Cross domain state cookie issue for oAuth using firebase functions while on the same domain

Tags: firebase, oauth, google-cloud-functions, cross-domain

I am implementing a oAuth login for a user for the firebase platform.

All works fine except if the user **has** **disabled cross domain cookies.**

Here is what I did.

1. From my domain/app the user gets redirected to a cloud function.
2. The could function sets the `state` cookie and redirects the user to the oAuth provider.
3. The user signs in to the oAuth provider and gets redirected back to another function to get the code etc. **And here is the problem**

On step 3 above the function cannot read any cookie if the user has disabled the cross domain party cookies from his browser. 
Both functions are on the same domain as seen below in the screenshot.

[image]

Is there any way I can remedy this issue? Am I doing something wrong in my approach?

I cannot understand why the 2 functions are treated as crossdomain.

**Update to include more info**

Request:

```
Request URL: https://europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net/authRedirect
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: [2a00:1450:4007:811::200e]:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Request Headers**

```
:authority: europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net
:method: GET
:path: /authRedirect
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cookie: signInWithService=false; state=877798d3672e7d6fa9588b03f1e26794f4ede3a0
dnt: 1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Headers**

```
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
cache-control: private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 218
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Sat, 03 Aug 2019 08:55:18 GMT
function-execution-id: c8rjc7xnvoy8
location: https://cloudapi-oauth.suunto.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=&scope=workout&state=1c8073866d1ffaacf2d4709090ad099872718afa
server: Google Frontend
set-cookie: state=1c8073866d1ffaacf2d4709090ad099872718afa; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 03 Aug 2019 09:55:18 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
set-cookie: signInWithService=false; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 03 Aug 2019 09:55:18 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
status: 302
vary: Accept
x-cloud-trace-context: 99a93680a17770f848f200a9e729b122;o=1
x-powered-by: Express
```

After that and once the user returns from the service he authenticated against the code that parses the cookies (or the function that handles that) is:

```
export const authToken = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const oauth2 = suuntoAppAuth();
  cookieParser()(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const signInWithService = req.cookies.signInWithService === 'true';
      console.log('Should sign in:', signInWithService);
      console.log('Received verification state:', req.cookies.state);
      console.log('Received state:', req.query.state);
      if (!req.cookies.state) {
        throw new Error('State cookie not set or expired. Maybe you took too long to authorize. Please try again.');
      } else if (req.cookies.state !== req.query.state) {
        throw new Error('State validation failed');
      }
      console.log('Received auth code:', req.query.code);
      const results = await oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken({
        code: req.query.code,
        redirect_uri: determineRedirectURI(req), // @todo fix,
      });

      // console.log('Auth code exchange result received:', results);

      // We have an access token and the user identity now.
      const accessToken = results.access_token;
      const suuntoAppUserName = results.user;

      // Create a Firebase account and get the Custom Auth Token.
      let firebaseToken;
      if (signInWithService) {
        firebaseToken = await createFirebaseAccount(suuntoAppUserName, accessToken);
      }
      return res.jsonp({
        firebaseAuthToken: firebaseToken,
        serviceAuthResponse: <ServiceTokenInterface>{
          accessToken: results.access_token,
          refreshToken: results.refresh_token,
          tokenType: results.token_type,
          expiresAt: currentDate.getTime() + (results.expires_in * 1000),
          scope: results.scope,
          userName: results.user,
          dateCreated: currentDate.getTime(),
          dateRefreshed: currentDate.getTime(),
        },
        serviceName: ServiceNames.SuuntoApp
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.jsonp({
        error: error.toString(),
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The above code does not find a cookie with the name `state`

So it fails here

```
if (!req.cookies.state) {
        throw new Error('State cookie not set or expired. Maybe you took too long to authorize. Please try again.');
      } else if (req.cookies.state !== req.query.state) {
        throw new Error('State validation failed');
      }
```

Did a little more search here is some more info.

The example I based on https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth

Looks like other users suffer from the same issue https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/569

I opened also this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/544

Comment: I'm specifically confused with the statement "not disabled cross domain cookies".
Cookies, by nature, cannot be shared across domains.

This answer might help, although it might only be related to Firebase Functions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935288

Comment: @Grant Timmerman i am saying that when a user has cross domain cookies on then it all works fine. If you see my functions are on the same domain , so I don't understand why they are treated (when saving a cookie) as cross domain. Take a look. Both functions are on the same domain. One sets a cookie and the other reads it. But when the user has disabled the cross domain cookies the second function cannot read anything.

Comment: @Grant Timmerman. Sorry that was a typo and fixed.

Comment: @JimmyKane, can you show the cookies from Inspector tab? Also make sure the cookies are generated with `/` else if it is generated with path `/authRedirect` or something else, it won't work. I would suggest you update the `Set-Cookie` cookie response in the question, also make sure that also has the right domain

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added all the info as you asked. Thanks for your time

Comment: @TarunLalwani you can also visit that endpoint your self (its open)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Response shows a Set-Cookie header for `state` and `signInWithService` cookies without a `domain` attribute:

```
set-cookie: state=1c8073866d1ffaacf2d4709090ad099872718afa; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 03 Aug 2019 09:55:18 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
set-cookie: signInWithService=false; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 03 Aug 2019 09:55:18 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
```

Set-Cookie without a domain means that what happens to the cookie on the way back to the server is browser-dependent. The "default", spec-compliant behavior: the browser will grab the FQDN of the service URL and associate it with the cookie. RFC6265:

> Unless the cookie's attributes indicate otherwise, the cookie is
> returned only to the origin server (and not, for example, to any
> subdomains)...If the server omits the Domain attribute, the user agent
> will return the cookie only to the origin server.

When the browser decides whether to *accept* the cookie from a HTTP service, one of the decision criteria is if the cookie is *first-party* or *third-party*:

- First-party cookie: if the resource (web page) you requested that triggered a call to `europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net/authRedirect` resides at `https://europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net/...`
- Third-party cookie: if the resource (web page) you requested that triggered a call to `europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net/authRedirect` resides at `https://some.domain.app.com/...`

In your case the FQDN of your "parent" app/page is likely different from `europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net`, thus these cookies are labeled as third-party. As you found out, a user can choose to block third-party cookies. As of August 2019, Firefox and Safari block 3rd-party cookies by default. Most (if not all) ad blockers and similar extensions also block them. This would lead the browser to simply ignore Set-Cookie header in the HTTP response from `europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net/authRedirect`. The cookie would not be sent back to 2nd Firebase function at `europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net/authToken` because it doesn't exist on the client.

Your options:

1. Host your app and Firebase functions on the same domain.
2. An architecture where all HTTP requests (app and Firebase functions) flow through the app; the latter acts as a proxy of sorts for the function calls. Here's [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788230/firebase-functions-custom-domain-with-single-page-app) to do it in Firebase.
3. Let's say your app and Firebase functions do reside in different domains. In Javascript you can create a small piece of middleware that calls the `/authRedirect` FB function, parses the response (incl. the cookies via Set-Cookie header), then writes the response (incl. cookies) back to the browser via `document.cookie`. The cookies in this case would be first-party.
4. Don't use cookies at all. The oAuth authorization grant flow that you're doing against `cloudapi-oauth.suunto.com` as the authorization server does not require cookies. You followed an [instagram-auth](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth) example that recommends this flow

> When clicking the Sign in with Instagram button a popup is shown which
> redirects users to the redirect Function URL.
>
> The redirect Function then redirects the user to the Instagram OAuth
> 2.0 consent screen where (the first time only) the user will have to grant approval. Also the `state` cookie is set on the client with the
> value of the `state` URL query parameter to check against later on.

The check against `state` query parameter is based on an [implementation best practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.1) for oAuth clients when authorization servers don't support the PKCE extension (`cloudapi-oauth.suunto.com` doesn't support it):

> Clients MUST prevent CSRF.  One-time use CSRF tokens carried in the
> "state" parameter, which are securely bound to the user agent, SHOULD
> be used for that purpose.  If PKCE [RFC7636] is used by the client and
> the authorization server supports PKCE, clients MAY opt to not use
> "state" for CSRF protection, as such protection is provided by PKCE.
> In this case, "state" MAY be used again for its original purpose,
> namely transporting data about the application state of the client

The key phrase is *securely bound to the user agent*. For web apps, a cookie is a decent option of implementing this binding but it's not the only option. You can stick the value of `state` into local or session storage, single-page apps do exactly that in practice. If you want to live in the cloud, you can stick `state` in Cloud Storage or equivalent...but you'd have to manufacture a key that uniquely identifies your client **and** this particular HTTP request. Not impossible but perhaps overkill for a simple scenario.

Comment: Just to make sure. I set the state cookie on `europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net` then redirect to `cloudapi-oauth.suunto.com` and that redirect back to `europe-west2-quantified-self-io.cloudfunctions.net` with the `state` as a param but on the redirect back there is where I cannot read the cookie to validate that against the param of the state. For example as seen in this repo from firebase (they do the same) https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth

Comment: What I am trying todo, is authenticate the user (an alread logged in firebase user) against a service to be able to get a token and then do API calls to that service. 

I thank you very much for this explanation but I think I am still a little confused on what I do wrong.

Comment: @JimmyKane What's the target service you're trying to call?

Comment: The suunto one as you see. 
So user gets redirected from  my app to a cloud function that sets the cookie and the client secrets and redirects to the suunto service. There he authenticates and gets redirected back to a cloud function that picks the state param + code to request a token. 
That second function (after the service auth) cannot read the cookie the first function set for the same domain (if the 3rd party cookies are off)

Comment: So app is Domain A 
Redirects to cloud function A is  Domain B -> Sets cookie (on the google functions domain). 
That function redirects to the service. That service needs no cokkie that is ok. He just needs to auth there. 
From that service he gets redirected back to the same Domain B with the state cookie in a param (get) but the cookie from that domain (The first function) is not read

Comment: Let's say you successfully acquire an access token from `cloudapi-oauth.suunto.com`. What service.are you calling with this token?

Comment: Some Endoints of that service. For example to retrieve a users workout. But that is not a problem.

Comment: _That second function (after the service auth) cannot read the cookie the first function set for the same domain (if the 3rd party cookies are off)_ - please update your question with details of this. Code and/or request/response headers that show how the 2nd function is called

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Hey what a great answer and so many things learned today! You are worth the 250points and more.